# Shell script capturing cursor terminal position on mac produces extra characters

Tags: bash, shell, tty, stty

I use the answer in https://askubuntu.com/questions/366103/saving-more-corsor-positions-with-tput-in-bash-terminal as a shell script, which works for me in extracting the current position on the terminal.

```
extract_current_cursor_position () {
    export $1
    exec < /dev/tty
    oldstty=$(stty -g)
    stty raw -echo min 0
    echo -en "\033[6n" > /dev/tty
    IFS=';' read -r -d R -a pos
    stty $oldstty
    eval "$1[0]=$((${pos[0]:2} - 2))"
    eval "$1[1]=$((${pos[1]} - 1))"
}

extract_current_cursor_position pos1
extract_current_cursor_position pos2

echo ${pos1[0]} ${pos1[1]}
echo ${pos2[0]} ${pos2[1]}
```

However, on the Mac machine, it produces extra `-en` with some new lines and spaces as shown below.

```
-en 
    -en 
        23 4
23 8
```

How could I avoid outputting the extra `-en` and new lines and extra spaces

Comment: Does this help? https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/173836/why-echo-n-doesnt-work-in-this-script-on-mac-terminal

Comment: That's not what I need. I'm trying to get the position on the terminal programmatically so I could make tput cup ${pos1[0]} ${pos1[1]}

Comment: It explains the `-en` you're seeing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `printf` instead of `echo -en`:

```
printf '\033[6n' > /dev/tty
```

`-e` and `-n` flags for `echo` are not shell standards and not all shells implement them. Some shells (including the one you are using) just echo them as though they were ordinary arguments.

`printf` is a shell standard. It automatically expands standard backslash escape codes in its format, and also prints a newline only if you tell it to (usually by putting a `\n` in the format). It can also do lots of other useful things, like pad values to a specific length.